# Rails model show info NoMethodError undefined method `all' for Article:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was created this project have been long time

I'm tried run it `rails s` found error
[image]

login `rails console` run `Article.all`

terminal show message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):3
NoMethodError (undefined method `all' for Article:Module)
```

`Article` model file:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
  searchkick

  has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :like_articles, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :catalog
  belongs_to :user
  has_attached_file :avatar

  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 100 } , uniqueness: true
  validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

update 1:

terminal using `Rails.application.eager_load!` found

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):4
        1: from app/models/article.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
TypeError (Article is not a class)
```

so, I'm delete all content of Article file

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
end
```

still found this issue

Comment: please include the code of Article, otherwise this is pretty hard to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible there's a module you've defined somewhere called `Article` that is shadowing the `Article` model? Anything that inherits from `ApplicationRecord` should be showing up as a `Class` not a `Module`.

Comment: it's say `Article` is not a class ?

Comment: If you look at your error, it says `Article:Module`. In ruby, classes inherit from module, so if it says it's a module, it is not a class.

Comment: I'm run `Article.class.superclass` display `Object` 

Comment: right. `Article.class` should return `Class` if it is a `Class`, and then `Article.class.superclass` would return `Module`. But if it's a `Module`, then calling `.class` will return `Module`, and calling `.class.superclass` will return object. Haha a bit confusing, but hopefully helpful.

Comment: ok, resolved, because I was change  App module name to Article in application.rb file